# Can I install cloud 9 for multiple users?

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have just installed [cloud 9](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/), and it is all working great for a single user, but I was hoping to install it so that multiple users could access their own workspaces.

Is there a plugin or setting I am missing? Or is this not a supported feature?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cloud9-ide collaboration in self hosted possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696224/cloud9-ide-collaboration-in-self-hosted-possible)

Answer (score 2):

try to run cloud9 with **bin/cloud9.sh -w ~/yourprojectfolder**

Comment: Thanks @Pradeep - I will try it. Is there any documentation for this, or link to relevant part of source code perhaps?

Comment: @BillyMoon yes it's my pleasure to share with you. [link](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9) this is the link that you can go through on this.