# cloud9-ide collaboration in self hosted possible?

Tags: share, cloud9-ide, collaborative-editing

Is it possible to have the collaboration and workspace sharing features in a self-hosted environment built from https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9?

Comment: unfortunately it's not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is possible with the newer version from https://github.com/c9/core, just pass `--collab` flag to the `server.js` script

Comment: After you use `--collab` the collaboration tab is there, but you don't actually get to use it, or have multiple users. However, you should be able to edit the same document on your laptop and desktop at the same time with a little orange cursor.

Comment: "The SDK is intended for plugin development. The collaboration features use mocked data sets because it lacks the back-end that is available on the hosted c9.io service. This allows you to create plugins on top of the collaboration APIs. It doesn't actually allow you to share the workspace with multiple users. You can however share the workspace with someone else and see each others cursors and selection. There won't be separate authentication as that is not a part of the SDK." https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cloud9-sdk/2nqFNMUHNqA/aNXNxLqpaPUJ

Answer (score 0):

The `--collab` flag activated the "Share" and "Collaborate" buttons for me, but the actual feature doesn't work. When adding a user, I get

`Error adding workspace member: Cannot POST /api/collab/0/members/add?silent=false&access_token=token`

Any solution to this? I feel like passing the `--collab` flag is more of a hack than anything and not intended to be run on self-hosted users, only for Cloud9 servers.

Comment: This looks like it should have been a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: SO was blocking me from commenting, apologies. I think it's because my account is not very active. Do you know of any way to really get collaboration working on a self hosted C9 instance?

Comment: See my comments on the answer. It seems the feature works for one person, but the "Collaboration" panel is disabled.